# Access UIButton using NSString

Tags: nsstring, uibutton

I have a view with 10 buttons each named Q1, Q2... Q10.

In another method I want to change the background image on the buttons however I am creating the button names from a string as such:

```
NSString *Q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q%d", i];
```

i is a integer which changes, is there any way I can access the UIButtons using the string Q so that I can then change the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597026/dynamically-name-labels-in-objective-c) by creating an array of labels, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15, Q16, Q17, Q18, Q19, Q20, nil];
```

Then accessing the buttons in the array by their index:

```
[[buttons objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```