# Convert string into IBOutlet UIButton object name

Tags: objective-c

There are 24 buttons that their labels change from a function driven by a UISegmentedControl that has 7 segments. There is also a UIPickerView with 9 different objects. These two dynamically change the labels of the buttons. Then, when a button is pressed i have to know the UIPickerView object that is selected, the UISegmentedControl selection and which button is this.

My function that receives and executes is this:

```
- (int)ButtonPlayController:(int)buttonPressed {

   NSString *button = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", @"button", buttonPressed];

   if (button.titleLabel.text == @"1C") {

       [self Play1C];

   }

  else if .....

}
```

The function receives a number (the button number) and combines the string name to create the `UIButton` name, e.g. if the function receives number 8 then the `UIButton` name is `button8` (i already have on my .h file: `IBOutlet UIButton *button8;`)

I remember these work on PHP but what about Object C? What do i have to change for this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable name from string in obj-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164860/variable-name-from-string-in-obj-c)

Comment: Also: [Obj-C equivalent of PHP's "variable variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables). Also also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090590/is-this-possible-to-call-variable-dynamically-in-objective-c and questions linked from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there some pointers for you in the comments, but I'm wondering why you are implementing your target-action this way?  Maybe there is a part of your program I don't understand but why not just pass the button as the argument to the receiver of the action:

```
- (IBAction)doStuffWithButton:(id)sender
{
    if ( sender.tag == 1 )
    {
        [self actOnOne];
    }
    else if ( sender.tag == 2 )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Like I say, this doesn't answer your original question, but maybe a different design pattern would make things easier?

Comment: My problem is that the labels of the buttons change dynamically from another function.

Ok, let me fully explain. There are 24 buttons that their labels change from a function driven by a UISegmentedControl that has 7 segments. There is also a UIPickerView with 9 different objects.

Comment: These two dynamically change the labels of the buttons. Then, when a button is pressed i have to know the UIPickerView object that is selected, the UISegmentedControl selection and which button is this.

Comment: I used a combination of the tag + Label name! Thank you!